# XSL show textbox when checkbox is checked using xsl and javascript

Tags: javascript, xslt, textbox, hidden

I need some assistance please. I am working on a form. When the user clicks on a checkbox, I would like a  textbox to open below the checkbox. I am using XSL and Javascript.

Here is the XSL

Note taker

```
            <div id="notes_checked">
              <label margin="3em">Comments:</label>
              <textarea margin="3em" rows="3" cols="20" name="comment1_text">
                <xsl:value-of select="//FORM/El[6]" />


              </textarea><input type="hidden" name="notes_checked" />
            </div>
```

and the Javascript function I am using a variable for document.getVariableById

```
//Function to show the notetaker comment textarea

function notetaker_show() {
    //Grab the condition of the notes radio button and assign it to c
    var c = $('notes');

    //If notes is checked, display the comments textarea, otherwise, hide them.
    if (c.checked) {
        $('notes_checked').style.display = '';
    } else {
        $('notes_checked').style.display = 'none';
    }
```

Right now the comment box is visible right away, and I want to hide it unless the notes box is checked.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `notes_checked` is the input type="hidden", are you sure you don't want to change the `display` property of the `textbox` named `comment1_text`?

Comment: I changed notes_checked to comment1_text.style.display etc.. and the textbox is still showing